# Magento2: Getting error in console Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb

Tags: magento2

I am getting an error in the console.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb in /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory-&gt;createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-&gt;create('Grazitti\\Mkt\\Mo...')
#4 /var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/Obj in <b>/var/www/vhost/abc/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php</b> on line <b>111</b><br />
```

Here is my code:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Abc extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel     
{


    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_resourceCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->_resourceCollection = $resourceCollection;


        parent::__construct($context,$resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
```

Please suggest, how to reslove?

Comment: please tell me you php and magento version

Comment: can you please share more details, when you face this error ?

Comment: Magento version is 2.2.6

Comment: Am getting this error on page and calling controller index/data.php in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to either use the abstract class `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` in the `__construct` function or get it via the object manager in a module. You can't do that with an abstract class. You need to use a none abstract class that inherits and implements it.

Comment: You need to use a none abstract class that inherits and implements it.-----You are right. Can you please share the code for this?

Comment: I have updated my comment. Please check whats the issue